# How to deal with small frequent transactions

Tags: mysql, transaction

I have been given the task to create a system in which users can buy intellectual property (broadly categorized, hard to explain what they are really buying) from the system and can transfer funds between each other.

For the purpose I have created a transactions table which holds the sender, receiver and amount. For performance purposes I cache the user's current balance in a column in the users table and update it with triggers on the transactions table.

However there is a type of product that is not really sold but rather kind of "rented", meaning that you pay as you go, and is not a fixed price depending on the usage you can get charged x dollars every y seconds where x and y are greatly variable. Generally speaking, though, both values will be quite low - x will be cents and y will be ~10 or less.

Hopefully you can see how this becomes a problem for my current set up, I can not use the transactions table for the obvious reason that it will get spammed with small transactions (which would be the correct way to use the system I suppose). The solution that comes to mind is to accumulate the price somewhere else and then charge once the user stops using the service, however another problem rises with that solution - what if the user starts the service, and then buys something else from the system and is left with an amount less than what accumulates.

Note: I'm talking about virtual currency in the system that the users pay for with real money.

What would be a proper way of dealing with this?

Comment: For an $0.x per y second product, are you adding a $0.x transaction every y seconds of usage, or recording "user a, time start, time end, spent (z * 0.x / y)", where z = end - start (in seconds)?

Comment: @Caleth that is indeed where I'm having my doubt. In the first case I will have a lot of transactions (not good I guess), in the second I can't be sure that in the end the user will have enough currency available, you see?

Comment: There are some things very unclear to me in your question. Can you outline how the usage time is measured technically? Does the server somehow gets informed from the user's client how much time the service or product in stake was used? In real time? And some expected numbers (number of users/transactions, clients&servers involved) would also be helpful.

Comment: You can use the current time as a proxy for end time running rentals. You can even precalculate a cutoff time for when they will run out of money.

Comment: Still unclear to me - voting to close as "unclear" until we see a clarification.

Comment: @DocBrown once the initial request for starting the service is sent then the client sends subsequent requests containing information about the usage, the user can not modify the client program because it is not running in a browser so there is no security issue there. The end is then marked either by a request or a timeout in the informing requests greater than some seconds. Unfortunately I can't provide information about projected use but I don't really see how this is relative to the question as it is more of a theoretical view point.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: there is a lot of context missing to give you a meaningful answer. The general architecture is important. As I suspected, it is a client/server system (which you originally did not mention with one word). Now, do the small frequent transactions have to be managed on the server? Or can parts of it, like the aggregation, happen on the clients? Another question: you used the word "service" in your question, but it is extremely unclear to me what you exactly mean with that, because that term is very ambigous.

Comment: Moreover you seem to have a picture in mind what that "service" might do, but currently I fail to see the same picture, that is probably the reason why I don't understand the gist of the problem. I recommend you edit the question and give us some more context or examples (I am sure that is possible without exposing anything confidentally).

Answer (score 1):

I personally would not have a column in your users table to represent the balance. Instead, wherever you are presenting the "balance", that comes from a summing query on your transactions table on that userid. However the users get money into their account, that also goes into the transactions table. Adding funds to an account is a positive transaction, and consuming funds to pay for a product or service is a negative transaction.

Thus at any point in time you can compute the balance for the user. You also have the added benefit of being able to account for the users balance and the ability to reconcile. It would be hard to account for the balance in the way you are doing it now.

Doing this also allows you to eliminate the trigger.

If you index your tables, structuring your users and transactions and querying as described here will perform well and scale.

Comment: But transactions will grow endlessly in time, a user may have hundreds of thousands of transactions especially if I have like 5 cent transactions every 2 seconds, computing that every time can not be a good idea also I frequently need to check if the user has enough currency because when they don't I must stop the service, you can't possibly tell me it's a good idea to compute say 100k records every 2 seconds for a single user.

Comment: "Doing this also allows you to eliminate the trigger. "  -- You say that as if having triggers is a bad thing.  This is exactly the sort of application where triggers excel, and in a DBMS with reliable transactions, it's perfectly safe.

Comment: Yes, my personal preference is to avoid triggers when possible. They have their use cases, and that is why triggers remain a feature of every major RDBMS. But my personal opinion is that triggers tend to be misused to the point I would call it an anti-pattern, like this author: http://devproconnections.com/sql-server/reasons-avoid-triggers

Comment: There's no substitute for understanding what you're doing, and abuse of a tool should result in indictment of the people doing the abusing, not the tool itself.  Most of what the blog post you cited is complaining about is a result of poor engineering, and there are a couple of spots where things the author suggests would fall into that category.

Comment: @php_nub_qq if you index your transaction table on user entity you wont be looking at 100k records each user lookup. If your transaction volume is that high, you will want to have a process, probably monthly to reconcile the accounts into a table, and then purge the reconciled transactions. Then calculating current balance is last month's balance plus transactions since.

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle that's not professional, a user (or government) may want to review their transactions from 10 years ago.

Comment: You can move your aged transactions into another table. When I said "purge" that was a bad word choice. I meant "purge" from the table that you are using for current transactions. I'd have a table for transactions in the current month, a table for transactions aged past that, and a table with user balances at each EOM. This would give the ability to account and reconcile going back as far as needed, but keep your current month transactions table lean and mean.

Answer (score -3):

You can use sessions. If this is happening in multiple sessions then store the transactions at the end of the session. Keep the details in DB only if they hold importance.